# Parsing XML via a shell script

Tags: xml, linux, parsing, xmlstarlet

i'm using xmlstarlet into a shell script to parse an xml file untitled app.xml with this command, just to get the content of  which is a string , and store it on "my_var" :

```
my_var=`xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//root/services/service[position=$i]" -v description -n /home/wissem/Bureau/app.xml`
```

then ,when trying to modify an other xml file untitled strings.xml with the output of the last command , using this command line :

```
find /root/AndroidStudioProjects/FacebookMenu/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml -type f -exec  perl -pi -w -e 's/name=\"text_'$i'\".*\<\/string\>/name=\"text_'$i'\"\>'$my_var'\<\/string\>/g' {} \;
```

i get the following error :

```
Substitution replacement not terminated at -e line 1.
```

i tried to understand the problem by changing severally the string that i'm parsing into my variable , i noticed that the problem appears when i have a "space" on the string !

to explain more :for  this_is_my_string  : it works

for  this is my string : i get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, if `$my_var` contains spaces, the shell will break arguments in `$my_var`. This should work:

```
-e "s;name=\"text_$i\".*</string>;name=\"text_$i\">$my_var</string>;g"
```

The double quotes prevent your argument from being split. The double quotes you want to be part of your argument were *already* quoted with backslashes, which protects them. And `$` variables *are* expanded when appearing in double quotes. I've also replaced `s/../../g` with `s;...;...;g` so that forward slashed don't need escaping. And I'm pretty sure there's no reason to escape the angle brackets.

I've tested the above with this procedure:

1. Create `/tmp/testq.xml` containing:

   ```
   <string name="text_100">Blah</string>
   ```
2. Issue:

   ```
   i=100
   my_var="room service"
   ```
3. Issue:

   ```
   find /tmp/ -name "testq.xml" -exec perl -p -e "s;name=\"text_$i\".*</string>;name=\"text_$i\">$my_var</string>;g" '{}' \;
   ```
4. Result to stdout:

   ```
   <string name="text_100">room service</string>
   ```

I don't use `-i` in the test above because I want to be able to rerun the test any number of times, but `-i` should not affect the validity of the `-e` expression.